# Convert a 10 digit string to int

Tags: c, string, integer

I 'm trying to convert a string to `int` or `long` value
but the result is not always the same.

This is the value:

```
char data[10] = "4647232508";
```

I have tried `atoi`, `atol`, `strtol` and `stroll`
but they don't produce the same result.

The converted values are different between themselves and from the expected result.

Comment: `char data[10]` does not have enough space for `"4647232508"`

Comment: @pmg Good observation.  `data` is not a _string_!

Comment: You should also post the code and the output produced by your tries.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it is a new generation. Demanding but not appreciating... gimme gimme gimme

Answer (score 4):

Note that for a string with 10 characters you need `char data[11]` the 11th element being the null terminator (`'\0'`), without it `data` cannot be treated as a string, it's a mere char array, using this non null-terminated char array as an argument of any of the functions you mentioned will invoke [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3), and is the primary problem in your code.

Using `char data[] = "4647232508";` is safer as the compiler determines the space required for the string including its null terminator.

**Additional Considerations:**

1. In a 32 or 64 bit system [`int` type size is usually 4 bytes or 32 bits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) and its maximum value is `2147483647` (2<sup>31</sup>-1), if you convert the string to `int` using `atoi` you are invoking, again, undefined behavior.

> [`atoi` return value](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/?kw=atoi):
>
> On success, the function returns the converted integral number as an `int` value.
> If the converted value would be out of the range of representable values by an `int`, it causes undefined behavior. See `strtol` for a more robust cross-platform alternative when this is a possibility.

Note that `long` in not guaranteed to have 64 bits or 8 bytes, it can also have 4 bytes, that is to say that [`atol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atol/), having the same behavior as `atoi`, can also invoke undefined behavior.

2. `strtol` also may not work as expected, for the reasons stated in the previous paragraph (long can have 4 bytes), but, as it's a more robust function, the behavior in case of overflow is well-defined.

> [`strtol` return value](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/):
>
> On success, the function returns the converted integral number as a `long int` value.
> If no valid conversion could be performed, a zero value is returned (`0L`).
> If the value read is out of the range of representable values by a `long int`, the function returns `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN` (defined in [`<limits.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)), and `errno` is set to `ERANGE`.

[`strtoll`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/) should output the correct result as `long long` should be at least 8 bytes in size and have max value of `9223372036854775807` (2<sup>63</sup>-1) . The [behavior of `strtoll`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoll/?kw=strtoll) is identical to `strtol` but for the out of range return values which are `LLONG_MAX` or `LLONG_MIN`.

Answer (score 1):

if it is for educational purposes maybe it is worth to write own one or improve this one

```
#define NOSTRING    1
#define INVSTRING   2
#define WRONGDIGIT  3

long long myatoll(const char *str, int radix, int *error)
{
    static char digits[] = "01234567890ABCDEF";
    long long result = 0;
    int sign  = 1;

    if(str && *str)
    {
        if(error) *error = 0;        
        if(*str == '-') { sign = -1; str++;}
        while(*str)
        {
            char *pos = strchr(digits, *str);

            if(!pos || pos - digits >= radix) 
            {
                if(error) *error = WRONGDIGIT;
                break;
            }
            result *= radix;
            result += pos - digits;
            str++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(error) *error = INVSTRING;
    }
    return result * sign;
}


int main(void)
{
    int errCode;
    printf("%lld\n", myatoll("-34565-67854", 10, &errCode));
    printf("The string was: %svalid\n", errCode ? "in" : "");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/asMxf4

Comment: @AhmedElsenbawy: This code is a good start: study it to understand how to convert a string to the number it represents. Then you can try and improve it: unlike `strtoll()`, it does not support initial white space, nor a + sign, does not support lowercase hex digits, nor bases larger than 16 and has undefined behavior on INT_MIN and for any number outside the range of `long long`. Its ability to return an error code is an simplification over `strtoll()` but it does not detect `"-"` as invalid.